# Android: ViewPager does not respect WRAP_CONTENT?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a ViewPager whose width wrap's to its contents, and is centered horizontally in it's parent.  The first code snippet uses a LinearLayout to create this effect, as shown in the first screenshot.  The second code snippet is my attempt to do this with a ViewPager instead of the LinearLayout, but the result is not the desired behavior, as shown in the second screenshot.

Any suggestions as to how I create the first effect, but using a ViewPager?

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView.setText("abcabcabcabcabc");
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        LinearLayout llayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        llayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        llayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        llayout.addView(textView);

        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        layout.addView(llayout);

        setContentView(layout);
    }


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView.setText("abcabcabcabcabc");
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        ViewPager pager = new ViewPager(this);
        pager.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        pager.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter());

        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        layout.addView(pager);

        setContentView(layout);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) 
        {
            collection.addView(textView, 0);
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) 
        {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
        {
            return (view==object);
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup arg0) {}


        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() 
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(ViewGroup arg0) {}
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use xml layout files and setContentView to them?

Comment: Happens to not be an option for me.  Though, if it doesn't work in code, I doubt it would work in xml.  (not that it matters, as I need to write the Layout in Java).

Comment: @ab11 So what is in the green part of your screen. If it is the other 'page' of content, what happens when you are on the far right or left. Otherwise can't you stick in a horizontal linear layout to get the effect you want?

Comment: @MorrisonChang.  The first image, with the green part, demonstrates the first code snippet which utilizes a linearlayout to create the desired effect.  I am confused as to why I can't create the same effect using the ViewPager, in the second code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your code for where Adapter called **instantiateItem()**

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) 
{
    collection.addView(textView, 0)
    return textView;
}
```

You are returning a TextView to be the page and the ONLY thing that you want to show.

The relevant part of the documentation is here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html

> A very simple PagerAdapter may choose to use the page Views themselves
>   as key objects, returning them from instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)
>   after creation and adding them to the parent ViewGroup. A matching
>   destroyItem(ViewGroup, int, Object) implementation would remove the
>   View from the parent ViewGroup and isViewFromObject(View, Object)
>   could be implemented as return view == object;.

Create a View with the layout that you want and return it there to have the effect you desire.

See the bottom of:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: Well, I would still expect the TextView to size itself properly, to comply to the WRAP_CONTENT parameter I gave it, as opposed to just filling the screen.  However, looking at the ViewPager source code, it is clear the ViewPager's child is forced to be the same dimensions as the ViewPager.  Unfortunately, it seems that the only way to modify the size of the ViewPager (to something other than filling the screen) is to override it's onMeasure method, which I'd prefer not to but it seems a reasonable solution here.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.onMeasure%28int%2Cint%29